# Maven Archetype and no extension files

Tags: maven, archetypes

When creating a maven archetype with "mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=", all files without extensions are ignored (Like Dockerfile for ex). How to keep these files ?

Maven version: 3.5.2

Comment: The issue has been reported to Apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-548?jql=summary%20%20~%20%22extension%22%20AND%20summary%20~%20without%20and%20project%20%20%3D%20%22Maven%20Archetype%22%20